# Misunderstanding a result from functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

While reading page 111 of [this book](https://books.google.com.jm/books?id=oOYQVeHmNk4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=applied%20analysis%20hunter&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aq0uVfOHArGOsQTW04HgDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=applied%20analysis%20hunter&f=false) I got confused as to what the authors were doing in their counterexample of why strong convergence doesn't imply uniform convergence. I summarise it below

> Let $X= l^2(\mathbb{N})$, and define the projection $P_n:X\to X$ by
>   $$P_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, x_{n+1},\ldots) = (x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n,0,0,0\ldots).$$
>   Then $||P_n-P_m|| = 1$ for $n\neq m$, so $(P_n)$ does not converge uniformly. Nevertheless, if $x\in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ is any fixed vector, we have $P_n x \to x$ as $n\to\infty.$ thus $P_n\to I$ strongly.

Why is it true that $||P_n-P_m|| = 1$ for $n\neq m$. I don't seem to understand what was done here.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Sorry, I forgot some details. see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m>n$, then $$(P_n-P_m)x = (0,\ldots,x_{n+1},\ldots,x_m,0,\ldots),$$
Therefore, $\|(P_n-P_m)x\|\le \|x\|$, hence $\|(P_n-P_m) \|\le 1$. Take $x=e_{m}$ (i.e. all elements are zeros except the $m$-th) to prove that $\|(P_n-P_m) \|= 1$.

In addition,
$$(I-P_n)x = (0,\ldots,x_{n+1},\ldots),$$
hence $$\|(I-P_n)x\|^2 = \sum_{j\ge n+1}|x_j|^2\to 0 \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty.$$

Hence, $P_n$ converges to $I$ in weak-* topology. Note that $P_n$ do not converge strongly!

Comment: Can you explain the part where you take $x=e_m$ and "prove that $||(P_n-P_m)||=1$"

Answer (score 0):

Let $n > m$, then $(P_n - P_m)(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, \ldots, 0, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n, 0, \ldots)$. Therefore $\|P_n - P_m\| \leq 1$. But if we take the sequence $e_{m+1}$ with a $1$ at position $m+1$ and zeroes elsewhere, we see $(P_n - P_m)(e_{m+1}) = e_{m+1}$, hence $\|P_n - P_m\| = 1$.